# Як перекласти з англійської - viewing frustum?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Зараз займаюся перекладом сайту з програмування комп'ютерної графіки. Планую зробити gitbook на основі перекладу. [Адреса сторінки](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/get-started).

Словосполучення viewing frustum стосується піраміди, але я не знаю як точно це перекласти.
Буду радий помічі)

[image]

Опис до рисунку:

> Якщо ви зв'яжете кути канви з оком, яке за замовчанням вирівняне із нашою декартовою системою координат, і продовжите лінії далі вглиб сцени, ви отримаєте певного роду піраміду, яку ми звемо *viewing frustum*. Будь-який об'єкт всередині *frustum* (або такий, що перетинає його) вважається видимим і з'явиться на зображені.

Comment: Небажано вставляти іншомовний текст, якщо його можна перекласти без втрати сенсу.

Comment: Frustum — зрізаний конус. (Нагадую, що піраміда — частковий випадок [конусу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Конус) в широкому сенсі.)

Comment: As a native English speaker with experience with 3D graphics software, I have never before heard the word "frustum"

Comment: This word occurs in the specialized literature about ray tracing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Якщо дослівно — **зрізаний конус** (або зрізана піраміда) **зору** (/огляду/погляду/бачення/тощо).

Якщо приблизно за сенсом і точність не така важлива — може, **[поле зору](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83)**?

Update 1: Є термін *[конус зору](http://polytechnic_uk_ru.academic.ru/33126/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83)* (рос. конус зрения) — але чи те він означає, невідомо.

Update 2: Російською перекладають як [пирамида видимости](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (іноді [конус видимости](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)) — [наприклад](//docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html): «использование наклонной пирамиды видимости (Oblique Frustum)».

Update 3: Українською теж кажуть *[піраміда видимості](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%22)* чи *[конус видимості](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%22)* — можливо, що це поширений/загальноприйнятий термін.

Причому *конус видимості* — навіть частіше за *піраміду видимості*.

Посібник «Геометричне моделювання і комп’ютерна графіка: використання бібліотеки OpenGL» (А. А. Лященко, В. В. Демченко, Є. В. Бородавка, В. В. Смирнов; Київський національний університет будівництва і архітектури; [2008](http://org2.knuba.edu.ua/pluginfile.php/16473/mod_resource/content/2/OpenGL_2008.pdf), [2009](http://manualsem.com/book/562-geometrichne-modelyuvannya-i-kompyuterna-grafika/25-proekciyi.html)), а разом з ним і [Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF'%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0)), каже **[зрізаний] об'єм видимості** — в загальному випадку, а як часткові:

- *[зрізаний] паралепіпед видимості* — у випадку ортографічної проекції;
- **[зрізаний] конус видимості** — у випадку перспективи.

Comment: Думаю, що переклад "поле зору", не зовсім вірний(хоча сам хотів запропонувати такий).
"A view frustum is defined by a field of view (fov)" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634570.aspx Тобіж view frustum визначається полем зору, але не є ним.